# Why extended Process in multiprocessing work slower than all other&

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm learning multithreading and multiprocessing and experimenting with them to understand these concepts better. I noticed that when I run an extended process it works much slower than all other ways, why it could be?
`

```
from time import time
from multiprocessing import Process


def count(n):
    while n > 0:
        n -= 1

t0 = time()
count(100_000_000)
count(100_000_000)
print(time() - t0)

pr1 = Process(target=count, args=(100_000_000,))
pr2 = Process(target=count, args=(100_000_000,))

t0 = time()
pr1.start(); pr2.start()
pr1.join(); pr2.join()
print(time() - t0)

class Proc(Process):
    def __init__(self, num):
        super().__init__()
        self.num = num
    
    def run(self):
        while self.num > 0:
            self.num -= 1

        
pro1 = Proc(100_000_000)
pro2 = Proc(100_000_000)

t0 = time()
pro1.start(); pro2.start()
pro1.join(); pro2.join()
print(time() - t0)

#casual time :  7.1526172161102295
#two processes time :  3.7792704105377197
#two extended processes time :  9.833416223526001
`
```

Answer (score 2):

The extended `Proc`, when running, makes `100_000_000` + `100_000_000` operations of accessing instance `self.num` attribute (in `run` function).
If you change `Proc`'s `run` function to the following:

```
def run(self):
    n = self.num
    while n > 0:
        n -= 1
```

you'll get another performance indicators. As I got the following:

```
6.945512771606445
3.5630362033843994
3.5521087646484375
```

Comment: tldr; Class attribute lookup is slow compared to local variables.